# Problem with checkout page

Tags: checkout

I am currently developing a website, but have a problem with the checkout page. When you have filled out the billing information, and select the Ship to the Address option and press continue, it doesn't do anything.and when I'm selecting shipping to another address also not works, please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are there any errors on the browser console? What about the magento logs (e.g. system.log)?

Comment: look at the json response from the ajax call when saving the billing address. Most probably there is an error there

Comment: Hi, I'm new to magento, can you please let me know How I Can check system.logs

Comment: hi, I fond sysytem.log from magento/var/logs that is:

Comment: 2015-08-27T08:35:12+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/alipay/form.phtml

Comment: @HiralUnadkat does the file exist?

Comment: Hi, I guess this will help you to debug your problem (+ other Magento problems that might come up in the future): http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: @SanderMangel: I can't find with this path frontend/base/default/template/alipay alipaly doesn't exist

Comment: @HiralUnadkat that would be your problem, reinstall the module to make sure the template exists

Answer (score 1):

Please use firebug extension to cross-check the issue. Actually, I guess one of your ajax request is breaking or not producing any response.

Follow the below steps.

- Install firebug extension using the following link
  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/
- After installing, right click anywhere of your webpage and "inspect element with firebug"
- Now Navigate to console tab.
- You can reload the page and start the checkout process again. Now you can see the ajax request and the response.
- If any ajax request is breaking, It will become red-in-color.
- If you can identify the breaking ajax request you must able to identify the file regarding to that one. Ideally there should be some error message.
- If you cant find the file still, Go to **system->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Log settings, Enabled Yes.**
- You have enabled logging in magento. Now whatever error/exception happens it must be in **magento/var/log/exception.log ** or ** magento/var/log/system.log**

Hope this helps. Let me know if you know more inputs.

Comment: Hi, I have checked system log and that is: 2015-08-27T08:35:12+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/alipay/form.phtml

Comment: Any Idea, what's problem?

Comment: Yes, The thing is Your magento is checking one file form.phtml inside alipay folder. Ideally It should have the template file inside that. But ther is no form.phtml. Form.phtml is missing. 
I Hope you have installed alipay module or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't find any folder name alipay in the template

Comment: Yeah. thats what. you dont have that file. Ideally you should have that file.  can u tell me what s the module you are using ? I hope u are using this one http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/alipay-payment-gateway-cosmocommerce.html

Comment: yes exactly that one

Comment: In that module, you have to have one file in alipay/form.phtml. You forgot to copy that file to your magento.

Comment: app/code/community/Nuber/Scopeviewer/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field.php on line 82
Here I found problem unddefined varlable, do you have any idea about this?